# Gulp - gulp-load-plugins not working

Tags: gulp, gulp-load-plugins

**Gulpfile.js**

installed via `npm install --save-dev gulp-load-plugins`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Require all tasks in gulp/tasks, including subfolders
require('require-dir')('./gulp/tasks', {
 recurse: true
});

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
console.log($);
```

No matter where I declare it, the output will always be {}. I even tried with longer version having the options, still no luck

Using `$.gulpif()`
gives

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'gulpif'
```

I even downloaded few starter packs from github but still getting same output. I'm kicking myself for moving from Grunt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the **package.json**, the plugin is saved as  `"gulp-if": "^1.2.5"`

so, I had to change the code `$.gulpif()` to `$.if()` since the plugin will strip the names by below logic

```
var pattern = arrayify(options.pattern || ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*']);
var replaceString = options.replaceString || /^gulp(-|\.)/;
name.replace(replaceString, '');
```

A silly mistake which took 4 hours of my time.

P.S: I don't think it'll load any plugins without the prefix gulp in it's name.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I did the same mistake and your post saved my sanity today.